# Fixing no return function for numpy.nextafter

Tags: python, numpy, return, variable-assignment

I'm trying to find the next floating point value after *a* towards *a + 1*. My code basically looks like this:

```
if a == 0:
    a = numpy.nextafter(a,a+1)
```

I expect to get a new *a* that's the next floating point value, as stated above, but all I get is "Assigning result of a function call, where the function has no return (assignment-from-no-return)". I've double checked my versions of NumPy and Python, and cannot figure out what's wrong.

Comment: This is a problem in `pylint`, which is a tool you seem to be running to detect common errors. The code will work just fine, just ignore the pylint messages. What version of pylint are you using?

Comment: I downloaded it about a week ago, but I'm embarrassed to admit I am not really sure- however, I trust that it is just a problem with pylint. Thanks.

Comment: @cbitt Please don't be embarrassed not to know something :) It seems to be [pylint issue #2694](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/2694), fixed just some days ago (the [commit fixing the issue](https://github.com/PyCQA/astroid/commit/9d5925fe603c9b6dd98477d638dd397d4226029a) includes `nextafter`, so this should solve your problem). According to the comments in the issue, it should be included in the next release, coming soon. See [What’s New in astroid 2.2.0?](https://astroid.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#what-s-new-in-astroid-2-2-0) (astroid is the module where this was fixed)