# Calling one function from another function or route using flask, python and sqlite

Tags: python, flask

I'm working on cs50 final project using flask, python and sqlite.  My problem is understanding how to either call 2 functions from the same route, or call one from another.  Or frankly just how to accomplish the goals of 1 - assigning an astro_sign based on day and month and 2- updating an sqlite db (signs.db) with the astro_sign to be 3 - displayed on index.html. I'm trying to use this example code https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-display-astrological-sign-zodiac-sign-given-date-birth/, but cannot get the zodiac function to work.  I've tried doing this without a function as if/elif statements in register route, but I get the "NameError: name 'astro_sign' is not defined" or "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'astro_sign' referenced before assignment" depending on the try.  I found an example on here that talked about local versus global variables and suggested adding "astro='', but then my signs.db is updated with an empty string as if function never runs.  I also tried using an @/zodiac route that redirects, but couldn't get it right.  I found this:  [How can we call one route from another route with parameters using python flask.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48148131/how-can-we-call-one-route-from-another-route-with-parameters-using-python-flask) but don't get it. The current try below, I tried putting the function in helper.py, but that completely kills the app. I can't figure out how to return the function, name the variable globally, and I'm extremely frustrated.  I pull the month and day as integers from an html doc:

register.html:

```
    <form action="/register" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="month">
                <option value= 1>January</option>
                <option value= 2>February</option>
                <option value= 3>March</option>
                <option value= 4>April</option>
                <option value= 5>May</option>
                <option value= 6>June</option>
                <option value= 7>July</option>
                <option value= 8>August</option>
                <option value= 9>September</option>
                <option value= 10>October</option>
                <option value= 11>November</option>
                <option value= 12>December</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="day" placeholder="Day of Birth" type="number">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="confirmation" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
```

Then in application.py, everything works until I try to determine zodiac sign and send to db.

```
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    """Register user"""
        # if user reached route via POST
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.form.get("username")
        month = request.form.get("month")
        day = request.form.get("day")
        password = request.form.get("password")
        confirmation = request.form.get("confirmation")
        astro_sign = ''

        #there are other checks in here that I removed to make this shorter
        #insert new users
        result = db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, hash, month, day) VALUES (:username, :password, :month, :day)", username=username, password=hash, month=month, day=day)

        # ensure username is unique
        if not result:
            return apology("username is already registered")

        # remember which user has logged in
        session["user_id"] = result

        #try to call the function from helper.py and update astro_sign 
        if astro_sign is '':
            zodiac_sign(day, month)
            return astro_sign

        #insert into signs.db that accepts astro_sign as text
        db.execute("INSERT INTO signs (user_id, astro_sign) VALUES (:user_id, :astro_sign)",
        user_id=session["user_id"], astro_sign=astro_sign)

        #redirect to login
        return render_template("login.html")


    # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
    else:
        return render_template("register.html")
```

in helper.py, my latest attempt now causes the app to completely crash after register.

```
def zodiac_sign(day, month):
astro_sign = ''
# checks month and date within the valid range
# of a specified zodiac
if month is 12:
    astro_sign = 'Sagittarius' if (day < 22) else 'capricorn'

elif month is 1:
    astro_sign = 'Capricorn' if (day < 20) else 'aquarius'

elif month is 2:
    astro_sign = 'Aquarius' if (day < 19) else 'pisces'

elif month is 3:
    astro_sign = 'Pisces' if (day < 21) else 'aries'

#you get the point

elif month is 11:
    astro_sign = 'scorpio' if (day < 22) else 'sagittarius'

return astro_sign
```

```
Any help would be so appreciated!
```

Comment: I think this question needs a bit of clarification: When you say your current code "completely kills the app", what's the actual error you're seeing? This could really help us understand what's going wrong. Also, the indentation looks a little off: I assume the contents of the `zodiac_sign` function are meant to be indented, but if not, that could definitely cause issues. Are you importing the `zodiac_sign` function from the `helper` module in `application.py`?

Comment: I'm sorry.  I'm so frustrated. My current code with the function in helper.py causes the screen to go completely white (with no recovery) after trying to register a new user.  In every case, I could not get astro_sign to update in the signs.db.  I did forget to say that I was importing the zodiac function into the application.py. Yes, I am.  Thank you for at least responding. I'm new to stack and trying.

Comment: I'm using the cs50 IDE. I wasn't getting an error, but I think I was trying to redirect from the zodiac function in helpers.py to route index.  I tried so many things that I may have copied the wrong version.  Sorry.

Comment: If that is the case, at the bottom of my helpers.py zodiac function there was return redirect("/").  Either way, I need help.  I can provide any code you need to see what is being imported.   I wish that I was not a virtual student, because I want to really understand this.  Either way, at the top of application.py:  "from helpers import apology, login_required, zodiac_sign".  When I ran "flask run", the white screen happens after registration.  I keep thinking this should be easily done in register route, but I can't figure out how.  I'm interested in any links or better learning strategies.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to give a full answer, since the code is somewhat incomplete currently, but I think the reason you're seeing a blank screen upon registration is due to this if statement in your `register` function:

```py
if astro_sign is '':
    zodiac_sign(day, month)
    return astro_sign
```

Let's think about what's happening at this point in the code: At the top of the `register` function, we had the line `astro_sign = ''`, and we don't alter this `astro_sign` variable until we get to this point, so this if condition (`astro_sign is ''`) will always evaluate to true, so the code inside it will always be called.

Next, we run the `zodiac_sign` function, which makes sense, as we need to find the astrological sign to include it in the output. That function `return`s a string. But then you don't store the result of the string in the `astro_sign` variable within your `register` function. I know that the `zodiac_sign` function calls the string variable it constructs `astro_sign`, but since these are two different functions, this won't affect `astro_sign` in the `register` function, and it will be left as `''` (an empty string).

Then, we `return astro_sign`. But this means the rest of the `register` function won't run! We return the empty string astro sign, so Flask sends an empty page to the browser as a result. What we *really* want to do is to alter the `astro_sign` variable in the `register` function, so that we can insert it into the database later on. So, maybe you should change the if statement to something like this:

```py
if astro_sign is '':
    astro_sign = zodiac_sign(day, month)
```

Now, the function should keep running after that if statement is run, and we'll eventually return the `login.html` template.

Edit: Also, you may need to update the `zodiac_sign` function so it is correctly indented, like so:

```py
def zodiac_sign(day, month):
    astro_sign = ''
    # checks month and date within the valid range
    # of a specified zodiac
    if month is 12:
        astro_sign = 'Sagittarius' if (day < 22) else 'capricorn'

    elif month is 1:
        astro_sign = 'Capricorn' if (day < 20) else 'aquarius'

    elif month is 2:
        astro_sign = 'Aquarius' if (day < 19) else 'pisces'

    elif month is 3:
        astro_sign = 'Pisces' if (day < 21) else 'aries'

    #you get the point

    elif month is 11:
        astro_sign = 'scorpio' if (day < 22) else 'sagittarius'

    return astro_sign
```

Comment: I tried if astro_sign is ' ': astro_sign = zodiac_sign(day, month).  First it gave me an error in the IDE "Assigning result of a function call, where the function has no return".  I looked that up and found <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54548783/fixing-no-return-function-for-numpy-nextafter> said that it was just a pylint error.  So I ran it anyways.  Got a 500 error on the screen and this in console.  
File "/home/ubuntu/finalproject/application.py", line 186
    return render_template("login.html")
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: What other code should I have included in my question that might help you see my errors?  Is there any easier way to make this work?

Comment: I had a typo that resolved the syntax error.  However, now I get the "Assigning result of function call where the function has no return"  with ValueError: NOT NULL constraint failed: signs.astro_sign in terminal and 500 error on the page.  Any fix?

Comment: I'm sorry for all of the comments, but I forgot to add that the console tells me DEBUG: INSERT INTO signs (user_id, astro_sign) VALUES (48, NULL).  I tried adding "return astro_sign and get TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.  Why is it returning null?

Comment: @Kelly5978 I thought it was just a formatting issue in your first post, but you might also need to fix the indentation of your `zodiac_sign` function? I've updated my answer to show you how the correct indentation should look

Comment: thank you for helping!  I have double checked the indentation.  I copied wrong, but correct in code. I was looking up the error <https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/3160> and decided to try to put `if astro_sign is ' ':  astro_sign = str(zodiac_sign(day, month))` to see if maybe I wasn't casting something right.  Result is 'None' being added to signs.db as astro_sign.  The program runs, but doesn't work. The function is returning NONE. My goal is to write my own horoscopes based on month/day, so is there a better way to write this if I can't get it to work?

Comment: as I try things, I get this error also.  sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object was created in thread id 139626732562176 and this is thread id 139626849403008.
I am thankful for any help.  I really want to learn this.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone runs into this problem, it ended up being a casting issue.  On index.html, I was using "numbers" for the months, but python read them as strings ("12").  I resolved the error with `<select class="form-control" name="month" type="number">`.  I could have also just put " " around all of the month numbers in helpers.py to make them strings.  @ouroboring helped me figure out the actual function, but I'm too new to vote.  Thank you!